# RSocket: How to send message from server (spring,webflux) to client (js) specific Observer(endpoint) from other place then Spring Controller

Tags: javascript, spring, websocket, spring-webflux, rsocket

I am new in **RSocket** world.
**Can you tell me how to send message from server to specific observer in javascript(Angular) application.** I am creating multiplayer pacman game where i have to send monster position from a server to a client. **I want to do this in other place then controller.** I know how to do this in spring to spring application because we can use RsocketRequester.route() to send message to specific endpoint on client side but i dont know how to create something like that in js environment. To be more precise I want to do the same thing like in websocket ( + STOMP). This is example:

Here i have exact endpoint. I can send there message using SimpleMessagingTemplate( in every place) but how to do something similar in rsocket?
Client side:

```
const ws = new SockJS(this.serverUrl);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    this.state = new BehaviorSubject<SocketClientState>(SocketClientState.ATTEMPTING);

    this.stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
        this.stompClient.subscribe('/pacman/update/monster', (monster) => {
            if (monster.body) {
                this.monsterToUpdate.next(JSON.parse(monster.body));
            }
        });
// other code ...

        this.state.next(SocketClientState.CONNECTED);
    }, (error) => {
        this.state.next(SocketClientState.ERROR);
    });
```

In RSocket (js) request looks like this and we can for example subscribe response from server easy only if we handle request in controller.(controller know where to send response)

```
socket.requestStream({
                data: {
                    'author': 'linustorvalds'
                },
                metadata: String.fromCharCode('tweets'.length) + 'tweets',
            }).subscribe({
                onComplete: () => console.log('complete'),
                onError: error => {
                    console.log(error);
                },
                onNext: payload => {
                    console.log(payload.data);
                },
                onSubscribe: subscription => {
                    console.error('Subskrybuje')
                    subscription.request(2147483647);
                },
            });
```

Server

```
    @Service
public class GameObjectSender implements ISender {

private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;

public GameObjectSender(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}

@Override
public void send(String destination, GameObject gameObject) {
    // Here i want to send monster position using RScoket
    this.template.convertAndSend(destination, gameObject);
}

@Override
public void sendWithTimestamp(String destination, GameObject gameObject) {
    // Here i want to send monster position using RScoket
    this.template.convertAndSend(destination, gameObject, Map.of("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis()));
}
}
```

Here i can use SimpMessagingTemplate to send message to specific place like '/pacman/update/monster' (js). Application flow for monster looks like (create 5 threads in service which move and send all time position to client side (GameObjectSender is injected here)):

Server:

```
 private void createMonsters() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Game.NUMBER_OF_MONSTERS; i++) {
        int[] position = positionSetterService.getStartPositionForFigure();
        Game.getGame().getMonsters().add(new Monster(i, position[0], position[1], Direction.NONE));

        new Thread(() -> {
            int idMonster = Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            logger.info("Stworzylem potwora o id: " + idMonster);
            Monster monster = Game.getGame().getMonsters().get(idMonster);

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    move(monster);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    logger.error("Przerwano watek potwora");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }, String.valueOf(i)).start();
    }
}

@Override
public void move(Monster monster) {
    int[] position = chasePlayer(monster);
    if (spriteCollisionService.checkCollisionWithMonsters(position[0], position[1])) {
        position[0] = position[0] - (position[0] % 32) + 16;
        position[1] = position[1] - (position[1] % 32) + 16;
    }
    monster.setPositionX(position[0]);
    monster.setPositionY(position[1]);

    Optional<Player> playerToRemove = spriteCollisionService.getPlayerWhoCollideWithMonster(position[0], position[1]);

    if (playerToRemove.isPresent()) {
        resetPreviousDirection();
        logger.info("Monster wpada na Gracza i go zabija");
        Game.getGame().getPlayers().remove(playerToRemove.get());
        this.spriteSender.send("/pacman/remove/player", playerToRemove.get());
    }

    synchronized (Game.getGame().getMonsters()) {
        Game.getGame().getMonsters().remove(monster);
        Game.getGame().getMonsters().add(monster);
    }
    this.spriteSender.send("/pacman/update/monster", monster);
}
```